# Code Signing with VSTS and GitHub Sources

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Like others I use GitHub for my open source projects. Now I want to use VSTS as build and release service instead of AppVeyor.

In future I want to sign all my NuGet packages.

but: where should I store my certificate file (pfx)?

- VSTS does not have a keyvault
- I do not want to store my pfx file on GitHub or any other public place

My Ideas

- I could store pem (base64) into a build var and create with openssl during the build the certificate (pfx)
- I could store the pfx file on a private and secured blob storage and download the pfx during the build

What is the best practise here?

Comment: You could still use Key Vault. Look at [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/najib/2017/03/07/protecting-secrets-using-vsts-and-azure-key-vault/) blog for some inspiration.

Comment: I didn't try [this example](https://www.harvestdatacorp.com/blog/2017/04/26/vsts-with-code-signed-pfx-certificates/), but it might work for you in a combination with [Download Secure File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/download-secure-file) VSTS task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your two ideas looks good for me. And since you are using VSTS which only support private repository, you can also create a private repository in your VSTS account to store the pfx file and then add a task in your build/release definition to get the file during the build/release.

Comment: I think I will go the private git way. Already got that idea by a local german evangelist but I thought maybe there is something else. Thank you.